Why can't I disable AppArmor on 24.04.1
Kinda overlapping question here. I'm trying to disable AppArmor system-wide. After doing this:
sudo systemctl stop apparmor
sudo systemctl disable apparmor

And rebooting, I have:
❯❯  sudo aa-status | egrep '^[0-9]'
48 profiles are loaded.
41 profiles are in enforce mode.
7 profiles are in complain mode.
0 profiles are in prompt mode.
0 profiles are in kill mode.
0 profiles are in unconfined mode.
17 processes have profiles defined.
17 processes are in enforce mode.
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are in prompt mode.
0 processes are in kill mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
0 processes are in mixed mode.

❯❯  sudo aa-enabled
Yes

❯❯  sudo systemctl status apparmor
○ apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/apparmor.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:apparmor(7)
             https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/wikis/home/

If I do something that violates the policy (in my case, creating a user namespace) I get stuff like this in my kernel log which seems to confirm AppArmor is in effect:
[  942.570952] audit: type=1400 audit(1735492407.323:89): apparmor="DENIED" operation="userns_create" class="namespace" info="Userns create restricted - failed to find unprivileged_userns profile" error=-13 profile="unconfined" pid=6227 comm="python" requested="userns_create" denied="userns_create" target="unprivileged_userns"


Old but ancient information in the AppArmor config on the Ubuntu Wiki is to disable it in GRUB boot settings - have you tried setting apparmor=0 and/or security="" to attempt to disable the kernel level loading of apparmor in /etc/default/grub and then ran sudo update-grub again? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor#Disable_AppArmor_framework)

Note from a security perspective, you should not do this, and instead, you should modify whatever apparmor policies exist on your system to allow whatever you're trying to do. Running without apparmor is intentionally insecure, and makes your system less secure.

Yes, but it's a useful experiment to confirm that AppArmor is the source of the behaviour I'm seeing. apparmor=0 in the kernel command line does indeed disable it. Is it a bug that the Systemd change didn't have the documented effect?

no, the boot-config files are generated as a part of the GRUB configurations. GRUB generation guides the boot-config generation, and the arguments you found in your other thread showing that it's enabled at the kernel boot arguments level indicate it was not disabled at the kernel level.  AppArmor service only loads the AppArmor profiles into the AppArmor kernel modules/system.  The AppArmor system itself operates at the Kernel level, not just the userspace/software level. If you read the description there it isays "Load AppArmor Profiles" - it doesn't disable AppArmor itself.

The Ubuntu Server docs say "AppArmor can be disabled, and the kernel module unloaded" with the Systemd operation. Now I think about it, I don't think that can ever have made sense, I don't think LSMs can even be kernel modules...
